# Steam will not run at all, no matter what I do. (22.04 LTS)

Tags: steam

I have tried every solution on this website and none of them have worked. When I type `steam` in the terminal, this is what I see:

```
$ steam
steam.sh[21591]: Running Steam on ubuntu 22.04 64-bit
steam.sh[21591]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[21661]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[21591]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
```

then, nothing happens. It exits and returns control back to the shell.

Please help.

Comment: Are you running Wayland or X11/Xorg? Video card? Nvidia? What version driver?

Answer (score 16):

I was having this issue. It looks like it's an issue with the desktop launcher file not launching steam correctly due to the system not using the correct GPU on NVIDIA prime systems. I found that there is a defunct steam running on my system already by launching it with the desktop launcher file.

Find the process: `ps aux | grep steam`

```
$USER  115599  0.0  0.0  10232  3800 ?        S    14:53   0:00 bash $HOME/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh -nominidumps -nobreakpad
$USER  115746  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        Zl   14:53   0:00 [steam] <defunct>
$USER  116535  0.0  0.0   9076  2204 pts/1    S+   14:56   0:00 grep --color=auto steam
```

Kill the process: `kill -9 115746`

Run steam again via the command line and it should launch this time around : `steam`

After that, modify your steam desktop launcher file at `/usr/share/applications/steam.desktop`
change line 38 from
`PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true` to `PrefersNonDefaultGPU=false`

*This requires root privileges, if you don't have root privileges you should be able to use steam via the command line.*

Reboot and the steam desktop launcher should work.

Comment: The "Preferred" GPU depends upon what your power settings are: Performance setting makes the more powerful GPU the default, other settings may not.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and changing the default NVIDIA 510 driver to 470 solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer is the correct answer, driver 510 creates also the following issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414618/google-chrome-getting-stuck-after-a-download

Installing driver 470 fixed bot that issue and the issue with Steam.