# Google Chrome getting stuck after a download

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

When I download something with Google Chrome, the browser gets stuck (it shows the hand pointer as it hovers over an link/button).

It's not frozen, as I can move and resize the window freely, but I cannot click on anything and shortcuts don't work either.

Can close it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

This happens on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.

So far the issue

- seems to happen when the browser asks for the save location of a file or an import dialog
- is independent of extensions
- is independent if a Google account is connected, or sync enabled
- affects all Chromium-based browsers, tested so far: Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, Brave

Comment: please post debug info.run Chrome from the command line and post the debug info here.

Comment: Hi Rishon, how can I do that? The log disconnects after Chrome starts.

Comment: Hi, follow this article: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en#zippy=%2Clinux

Comment: The log generated is to big to paste it inside this comment and astebin has a limitation of 512KB which of course it exceeds it.

Comment: Even if I remove all log before the download happens it still goes around 900KB.

Comment: I also:
- tried disabling every extension I had installed, but still the issue occured.
- tested on other chrome based browsers: so far only Brave and Google Chrome share the symptoms. Opera and Vivaldi have no issue.

Comment: i would suggest using chromium based browsers like microsoft edge as a workaround. or you can report to google as an bug.

Comment: I prefer to keep using Chrome, I am quite used to, and had different issues with other browsers which I didn't had with Chrome.

So far I managed to pinpoint the fact that the issue is related to my profile. 
A clean Chrome with no profile is able to download without any problems. 

Another issue, which might be related to the profile is that I cannot reset the browser, I have to manually delete the .config/google-chrome directory.

Comment: Another thing I found out is that it's not specific to a profile. Using sync option with any other account results in the same problem.

Comment: So I tried to switch to Vivaldi browser, I imported everything from Chrome (history, bookmarks, passwords) and now it has the same issue.

Comment: Found out another thing! 
The issue occurs when a dialog is used (such as download dialog, or import dialogs), it doesn't matter if there is a profile or sync happening.

If the download occurs without asking for save location it works without issue. 

This leads me to believe that despite the dialog being closed, the main window of the browser isn't able to retrieve the focus of the inputs at all.

Comment: ahah! now it makes sense. your data has been corrupted! remove all the data, and reinstall chrome. there is no other way.

Comment: no it's not the data, it was the driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so the issue is Nvidia driver 510.

After bumping into the same issue as the one asked about in [Steam will not run at all, no matter what I do. (22.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407100/steam-will-not-run-at-all-not-matter-what-i-do-22-04-lts) I thought the solution could help with this issue as well.

What made me think this was the case was that the browser didn't freeze but I couldn't interact with it at all; the browser was working (for example: if it was a big download the download loader was running, not freezing). And the issue occured whenever a dialog from browser was opened (download, import, print, etc.).

So if anyone encounters this issue and has Nvidia driver 510, downgrade to 470 and see if it works.

Comment: Same issue with 515

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

Explanation:

[Google Chrome freeze uploading a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404550/google-chrome-freeze-uploading-a-file/1404974#1404974)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I changed the distro on my machine though, so I cannot test your answer. That's why I will keep my answer since that also worked.

Comment: Can confirm, this command fixed my chrome freezing issue on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: confirmed, worked in February 2023, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, all updates/upgrades up to date - one thing - I had to **restart the pc for this change to take effect**

Answer (score 2):

Extending other answers and some additional thing I did worked for me:

- `sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome`
- turn off hardware acceleration

  - Go to chrome settings > search Hardware in the search box > and Hardware acceleration > Turn it off
- Reboot the PC

Comment: the problem was HW acceleration in my case

Comment: Seems like the problem really is the nvidia driver. Do have a Nvidia card?

Answer (score 0):

My resolve is delete directory `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome`.

Comment: Hi @La An Vong, thanks for answering but this was my first try and wasn't something which helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with Event Sounds. Chromium-based browsers freeze when the download is completed and they try to play the notification sound.

Disable event sounds with gsettings or Dconf:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false

Fabiano Bovo - Brazil